# Using JavaScript, how do I get this code to autofill Username & click button, delay, or wait, then autofill Password & click log in?

Tags: javascript

```
document.getElementsByName("Username")[0].value = 'FamilyGuy'

function myFunction(){
    //pag 1, delay a second. Giving user name time to fill
    document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
}
//delay
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);

function myFunction(){
    //page 2, delay a second. Giving passwrd time to fill befor logging in
    document.getElementsByName("Password")[0].value = 'this1sth3p4ssw0rd!'
}
//delay
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);

document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
```

//I am using this extension using this extension
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNMiJ.png

Comment: add Html part of your code

Comment: @NileshMishra Any suggestions on what that might look like? Sorry, kind of a newb here, jaja.

Comment: I am asking for  full code in question so any one can easily debug  @SyntaxEyes , javascript+HTML

Comment: @NileshMishra This is the full code. I am putting it into the extension called Page Manipulator - https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/page-manipulator/hfhjgoiepgnobooahplnlfcbgaakilib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setTimeout is an asynchronous function. It doesn't pause the execution of code that follows it.

This means that, in your example code, the two timeouts will run simultaneously, and your login button will be pressed immediately. To fix this, put the second timeout at the end of your first function, rather than in the main body of code. Also put the pressing of the login button inside the second function.

```
document.getElementsByName("Username")[0].value = 'FamilyGuy'


function myFunctionB(){
    //page 2, delay a second. Giving passwrd time to fill befor logging in
    document.getElementsByName("Password")[0].value = 'this1sth3p4ssw0rd!'
    document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
}

function myFunctionA(){
    //pag 1, delay a second. Giving user name time to fill
    document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
    
    //delay
    setTimeout(myFunctionB, 1000);
}

//delay
setTimeout(myFunctionA, 1000);
```

I don't know the way the NextButton operates, but the use of a delay to wait until the Username value changes is probably unnecessary. Consider using the following code:

```
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementsByName("Password")[0].value = 'this1sth3p4ssw0rd!'
    document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
}

document.getElementsByName("Username")[0].value = 'FamilyGuy'
document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
    
//delay
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That resolved it!

Answer (score 0):

This may be one possible implementation to achieve the below-described (what is assumed to be the desired) objective:

1. A screen with input-boxes username, password and buttons 'Next', 'Login' is rendered
2. After waiting for some time (say 1.5 seconds), username is auto-populated
3. Another delay of 2 seconds and 'Next' button click is programatically triggered
4. After delay of 2 seconds, password is auto-populated
5. Finally, another delay of 1 second and 'Login' button is programatically triggered.

The time-delays are just randomly assigned in the snippet and may be altered as required.

It would definitely helpful to understand the context within which this is being used - to cater a more suitable answer.

```js
const btnClicked = name => console.log(`${name} button clicked `);
setTimeout(
 () => {
  document.getElementById("Username").value = 'FamilyGuy';
  setTimeout(
    () => {
      document.getElementById("NextButton").click();
      setTimeout(
        () => {
          document.getElementById("Password").value = 'this1sth3p4ssw0rd!';
          setTimeout(
            () => {
              document.getElementById("LoginButton").click();
            },
            1000
          )
        },
        2000
      )
    },
    2000
  )
 },
 1500
);
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input id='Username' />
<button id='NextButton' onclick='btnClicked("Next")'>Next</button>
<input id='Password' />
<button id='LoginButton' onclick='btnClicked("Login")'>Login</button>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```